# Postgres create policy returns infinite loop error or unexpected result

Tags: sql, postgresql, infinite-loop, policy

I'm trying to understand SQL policy but ran into a problem. I have a table `employee` with columns `data_center_id`, `role` and `login`. Administrator role can only see employees that work in same data center as administrator. How can I do it using `CREATE POLICY`?

Why does this code:

```
select * from employee;
```

return an infinite loop error when I create policy?

```
CREATE POLICY 
    admin_employee 
on 
    employee 
to 
    administrator 
using (data_center_id in 
    (select data_center_id from employee where login = current_user) );
```

I also tried this variant:

```
CREATE POLICY 
   admin_employee 
on 
   employee 
to 
    administrator 
using (data_center_id in 
    (select data_center_id where login = current_user) );
```

but

```
select * from employee;
```

returns only one line with `current_user`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Pretty sure the infinite loop is coming from here: `...in   (select data_center_id from employee where login = current_user)`. The `select * from employee;` starts the policy check which runs the subquery `select` which runs the policy check which runs the subquery `select` and so on. Not sure yet how to break out of that. To your question add the complete table definition for the `employee` table.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thanks for the explanation, I didn't know it worked like that. I solved the problem by creating a new table wich connects `employee` table and `data_center` table to avoid `select` in the same table.

Comment: It would be a security hole to create a policy for SELECT that that allows you to do a SELECT without a policy check.

Comment: There must be some policy defined on `employee`. What is it?